# What's a good word for a judged member of a tight-knit community?

Tags: single-word-requests

I'm trying to describe a character in a small-town community who is still judged based on her actions in the past, but I want it to be clear and concise. Is there a word for this type of person?

Comment: Can you add a sample sentence or two where you would like to use the term, with a ____ where the word would go? This will help us understand the kind of word that would best fit.

Comment: she wears the scarlet letter

Comment: @devc2 Unless, perhaps, she was murdering puppies or stealing from the poor, etc, etc... I think you're thinking of *pre-judged* ;)

Comment: @J it fits because she mentions small town and small towns are usually poked fun at by associating them with outdated beliefs

Comment: I think that "shunned" is often used in this context.

Answer (score 5):

I suggest ***stigmatized***. Here is the first definition of *stigmatize* at [Oxford Living Dictionaries](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/stigmatize):

> Describe or regard as worthy of disgrace or great disapproval.

Answer (score 4):

I would describe a character in a small-town community who is still judged based on her actions in the past as an *outcast*.

M-W:

> [*outcast*](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/outcast): one
>   that is cast out or refused acceptance (as by society)

Answer (score 1):

*Unforgiven*

I'm sorry, the only definitions I'm finding are for "forgive".

Answer (score 1):

I couldn't think of a word, but in describing the character, *tainted* came to mind.

For example:

> As the elders gathered, it was clear that despite ____'s years of
>   service to the commune, her tainted past still permeated around her
>   like a shadow of shame, following her around, reminding others of what
>   once was, of the mistakes of the past.